# `string.replace` doesn’t change the variable

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```js
var variableABC = "A B C"; 
variableABC.replace("B", "D") // Wanted output: "A D C".
```

but `variableABC` didn’t change:

```js
console.log(variableABC); // "A B C"
```

I want it to be `"A D C"`.

Comment: Strings are not mutable, you have to pass the result somewhere, probably back to itself like the answers below are doing.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

According to the Javascript standard, `String.replace` isn't supposed to modify the string itself. It just returns the modified string. You can refer to the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more info.

You can always just set the string to the modified value:

`variableABC = variableABC.replace('B', 'D')`

Edit: The code given above is to only replace the first occurrence.

To replace all occurrences, you could do:

```
 variableABC = variableABC.replace(/B/g, "D");
```

To replace all occurrences and ignore casing

```
 variableABC = variableABC.replace(/B/gi, "D");
```

Answer (score 9):

Isn't string.replace *returning* a value, rather than modifying the source string?

So if you wanted to modify variableABC, you'd need to do this:

```
var variableABC = "A B C";

variableABC = variableABC.replace('B', 'D') //output: 'A D C'
```

Answer (score 8):

Strings are always modelled as **immutable** (atleast in heigher level languages python/java/javascript/Scala/Objective-C).

So any string operations like concatenation, replacements **always** returns a new string which contains intended value, whereas the original string will still be same.

Comment: Just FYI: Ruby strings _are_ mutable.

Comment: @Jimmy Thar is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clobber all of the instances of a substring out of a string without using regex you can using:

```
    var replacestring = "A B B C D"
    const oldstring = "B";
    const newstring = "E";
    while (replacestring.indexOf(oldstring) > -1) {
        replacestring = replacestring.replace(oldstring, newstring);
    }        
    //result: "A E E C D"
```