# Why is my str.replace line not working?

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I'm making a function that takes a string, cuts the first half (leaving middle character if odd string.length) and adds first half to end of string.

For some reason  my function only partlyworks: it adds the substr to the end but doesn't cut it from the start. I tried .replace but not working.

What am I doing wrong? And/or is there a better way?[image: my function..]

Comment: You've got `'substr'` as the first argument to `.replace()` - the **string** `'substr'`, not the variable.

Comment: Why did you post your code as an image?

Comment: Or to put it another way: Don't post code as a picture, post it as *code*.

Comment: If it weren't for the `'substr'` thing, this would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162097/node-js-string-replace-doesnt-work (and many, many others).

Comment: just posted it as an img out of bad habit and <3 for colours in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` *returns* a new string with the replacement, it doesn't modify the string you call it on.

Additionally, as [Pointy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905065/why-is-my-str-replace-line-not-working/31905082#comment51724140_31905065), you've passed the literal string `'substr'` in, rather than passing in the variable `substr`.

So:

```
s = s.replace(substr, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

a friend just gave another way to write a function that does what I wanted mine to do . I'm an amoeba and you're all wizards

```
function doit(s){
split = s.length /2;

if(split % 2 !== 0) { split = split-1; }
var partOne = s.slice(0, split);
var partTwo = s.slice(split + 1, s.length);

return partTwo + partOne;

}



alert(doit('123456789qwertyuio'));
```